# How to use densities for Naive Bayesian classification?

Tags: naive-bayes

This is a simple question I think.

I am using the following R package for non parametric naive Bayesian classification:

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/rdrr.io/a/cran/naivebayes/man/nonparametric_naive_bayes.html

However, it uses the pdf of the features directly and this is problematic as some densities return a value greater than 1.

Can I standardise my features in some way to prevent this ?

Cheers

Duane

Comment: Why is it "problematic"? Probability densities just can be >1, nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Yup I’m not that disputing that. However, the package above uses a log sum and then an arg max. The log of a value greater than 1 is positive. The log of the density for some classes is positive and others are negative. This will affect classification

Comment: why exactly? You certainly can say that positive value is greater then the negative value, same as compare positive and negative values. After taking log ordering of values doesn't change. If you don't like the logs, you can take exp of them, but this wouldn't change anything about the results. Moreover you don't need use log likelihood, you can use likelihood alone.

Comment: Hey thank you for the comment. If one samples features density is above one and the other is below one then in the log sum trick won’t they have a negative interaction for the classification? If I use the exp then won’t I run into numerical issues ?